# Trying to take a string of characters copy part of it to and adjacent cell and shorten the original string

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take a list of part numbers in the format 0000-000X0 where 0000-000 is the part number (variable) and X is in the string but it is only there to get a seperation between the Quantity which would be the last character (always below 10 so only one digit).

I'm trying to take the last part number string (10 characters) shorten that to only the part number and paste that in the active cell (so it deletes the other part numbers) and past the last cells quantity (the last digit in the cell) on the adjacent cell (same row one coloumn to the right)

There are multiple part numbers in a cell such that it could look like 
`0000-000X1 0000-001X2` etc...

I'm not great with VBA and have been trying to teach myself, so the issue I'm running into first is that I can't get it to paste what I think is the correct selection.

Also I'm not too sure on if I am using my string variables correctly.

I am using it by clicking on the cell and running the macro so referencing should just be with the active selection.

My code looks like this

```
Public Sub name_help()
Dim Quantity As String
Dim Number As String
Dim NumberShortened As String
Dim Start As String

ActiveCell.Select

Start = Selection

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Quantity = Right(Start, Len(Selection) - (Len(Selection) - 1))

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

Quantity.Paste

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select

Number = Right(Start, Len(Selection) - (Len(Selection) - 10))

Number.Paste

NumberShortened = Left(N, Len(Selection) - (Len(Selection) - 8))

NumberShortened.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: I have looked into that but for my specific application having all of them split into a row or column isn't super beneficial to me. I just want the last part number in the cell I started with and the quantity to appear directly right of the start cell.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the following should work.  There is no error checking, but that can be added if the basic concept is what you want.

```
Option Explicit
Sub name_help()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim V As Variant, V1 As Variant
    Dim vRes(1 To 1, 1 To 2) As Variant

Set R = ActiveCell
V = R

V1 = Split(V)

vRes(1, 1) = Split(V1(UBound(V1)), "X")(0)
vRes(1, 2) = Split(V1(UBound(V1)), "X")(1)

R.Resize(columnsize:=2) = vRes

End Sub
```